# where can I find the codes used on Skyvector charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

on https://skyvector.com/?ll=51.25181634927654,3.6845398064171233&chart=301&zoom=1 at N51°14.00' E3°46.96' is see a code "EBW" (blue circle with in-pointing teeth). I searched everywhere but couldn't find what "EBW" stands for. On Google maps I only see agricultural land there. 
I also see similar codes like EHM and EBM, and would like to find an index for such codes.

Comment: The EBR and EBM codes stand for **E**urope **B**elgium **R**estricted / **M**ilitary airspace (see [AIP 5.1](https://ops.skeyes.be/html/belgocontrol_static/eaip/eAIP_Next/html/eAIP/EB-ENR-5.1-en-GB.html) and [AIP 5.2](https://ops.skeyes.be/html/belgocontrol_static/eaip/eAIP_Next/html/eAIP/EB-ENR-5.2-en-GB.html)). Likewise EHM is the same for the Netherlands (all Dutch ICAO codes start with EH). I guess EBW would refer to a warning then, but I'm not sure since I couldn't find anything in the AIP.